# Using an array to transfer file names into workbook with multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Public Sub GetSOPFiles()
    '   Set folder path
        Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\SOP Audit Excel Prototype"

        Const FileExt As String = "docx"

        Dim Result As Variant
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim MyFile As Object
        Dim MyFSO As Object
        Dim MyFolder As Object
        Dim MyFiles As Object
        Dim dept As Variant
        Dim deptCodes() As Variant

        Set MyFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set MyFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
        Set MyFiles = MyFolder.Files

    '   Research built-in Result function in VBA
        ReDim Result(1 To MyFiles.Count)

        Dim vData As Variant
        Dim sTemp As Variant

    '   Use a For loop to loop through the total number of sheets
        For i = 1 To 12
    '       Setup Select to determine dept values
            Select Case i

                Case 1
                    deptCodes = Array("PNT", "VLG", "SAW")

                Case 2
                    deptCodes = Array("CRT", "AST", "SHP", "SAW")

                Case 3
                    deptCodes = Array("CRT", "STW", "CHL", "ALG", "ALW", "ALF", "RTE", "AFB", "SAW")

                Case 4
                    deptCodes = Array("SCR", "THR", "WSH", "GLW", "PTR", "SAW")

                Case 5
                    deptCodes = Array("PLB", "SAW")

                Case 6
                    deptCodes = Array("DES")

                Case 7
                    deptCodes = Array("AMS")

                Case 8
                    deptCodes = Array("EST")

                Case 9
                    deptCodes = Array("PCT")

                Case 10
                    deptCodes = Array("PUR", "INV")

                Case 11
                    deptCodes = Array("SAF")

                Case 12
                    deptCodes = Array("GEN")
            End Select

'       Loop through files in directory
        j = 0
        For Each MyFile In MyFiles
'           Limit files by file extension
            If InStr(1, MyFile.Name, FileExt) <> 0 Then
'               Explode file name into array and only pull files with defined dept codes
                Dim toSplitFileName As Variant
                toSplitFileName = Split(MyFile.Name, "-")
                For Each dept In deptCodes
                    If dept = toSplitFileName(3) Then
                        ReDim Preserve Result(0 To j)
                        Result(j) = MyFile.Name
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                Next dept
            End If
        Next MyFile
'       Send array to worksheet
        Range("A1:A20").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Result)
    Next

    End Sub
```

Okay, you were right about the out of range part. I edited my code and posted it.

What I am trying to do here is pull file names, sort them after parsing their file name (using SELECT to define the different values I am looking for), then transfer those filenames as an array over to each relevant sheet in the workbook.

I had a working (somewhat) function and it was really slow so after receiving some advice on here to send the results to an array then use VBA to transfer directly to worksheets; this is what I have so far.

I'm trying to figure out how I could send the data to each sheet now...I have it working in one sheet. Say it loops through and finds all the files for SELECT Case 1, it sends all of those filenames to column A in Sheet 1. Same for Case 2, etc.

At the moment, it's just populating all of the cells in the defined range with one file name over and over again.

Like so...

[image]

Thank you to all of Stack Overflow! After 3 book purchases and a few posts on here so far, I feel I'm starting to make some headway into VBA. Still have a lot to learn though.

Comment: If `Result`'s upper-bound is `j-1`, then `j` will be out of range, right?

Comment: Your comment was the answer to my first question; before I did my edit. I feel like the proper etiquette is to mark that as the answer, then move my edit to a New Post but I don't see a way to mark a comment as an answer. Advice on forum etiquette here would be appreciated.

Comment: I can add it as an answer, or you can add an answer to your own question. As far as forum etiquette goes, yes it is preferable to ask a new question, instead of editing the old question.

Comment: Did notice that you have received answers to other questions you have had in the past, and some answers aren't checked yet. Feel free to do so if you feel the answer truly answers your question.

Comment: wow ^^^ now the above is a great example of how SO could work in terms of communication and response!

Comment: Added new code, changed title, and added to msg body. Thanks SO.

Comment: I have it working somewhat now.

Worksheets(i).Range("A1:A" & j).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Result)

Comment: This mini-markdown formatting isn't working for me lol...I keep trying though.